# Column- or row-wise hierarchical clustering using Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I'm doing a hierarchical cluster-analysis of a dataframe with python Scipy, and was wondering if the clustering is column-wise-oriented or row-wise-oriented? I get different results depending on whether I transpose the dataframe or not before calculating the distance matrix.

I read somewhere that the "standard" for clustering is to do it column-wise, however I can't seem to find anything about this in the scipy-documentation.
Anyone who knows?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's wondering the same thing; basic testing with a simple dataframe showed that it is *row-wise*